# Is this expression "she busied her new home herself" a common usage of "busy"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

It sounds like the lecturer is [speaking](https://youtu.be/zH2s4XSEWO0?t=352)

> Can you even do this? 
>   like the computer busy programs itself

I guess that lecturer's meaning might be "the computer busy itself with (writing) programs"

[dictionary.cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/busy) gives this example of "busy"

> I busied myself with tidying up my desk.

[lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/busy) gives this example of "busy"

> ‘she busied herself with her new home’

With the lecturer's usage, this example sentence could be rewritten as "she busied her new home herself"

Is this expression a clear and normal using of "busy"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misapprehension unlikely to be common enough to be of interest for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is saying basically, not busy.

"Can you even do this? like the computer **basically** programs itself"